# How to Periodically Update Display Image? - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, graphics, blocking, display

I am writing a program that renders fractal images. It takes time to generate these images, and I want to monitor the progress of the program in real time.

Here is the structure of how I imagine my code should be structured:

```
// create a window to display the image as it gets rendered
CreateDisplayWindow();

// as long as you are not finished rendering the image,
while(!doneRendering)
{
    // render a bit more of the image.
    RenderASmallPartOfMyImage();
    // update the screen if it has been too long since the last time it was updated.
    if(timeSinceLastDisplayUpdate >= displayUpdatePeriod) UpdateDisplayWindow();
}
```

I have searched google and MSDN for hours trying to find a simple way of achieving this. I only find complicated answers.  I imagine that the *right* answer will be very simple.

**To summarize my question:** How Do I create a "display window" that can be periodically updated that will not block the execution of my `while(!doneRendering)` loop?

Comment: How will your app do anything if it is always in that while loop?  Explore the power and mysteries of the Timer

Comment: @Plutonix I am currently using a Windows Form and a Timer to achieve this, but it horribly violates the whole OOP idea of encapsulation. Right now, the windows form has all the information about the fractal inside it.
I just want to create a generic "window" that runs in the background, and send it a new image to display every once in a while from my loop that renders my image.

Comment: Put your fractal logic in another class. Have its logic run on a secondary thread (probably not out of the thread pool).  If there are points in your calculation where it makes sense to update the your image, send the data for the update over to the main form (or to another non-modal form) using `Control.Invoke`. If there aren't natural update points in your calculation, use a timer on the form to go fetch the data.  If you pick the latter way, you'll need some synchronization/locking to prevent issues.  If you post some more complete code (or even pseudo-code), we can post some back in reply.

Comment: Do what @Flydog57 said. Use a thread. *...but it horribly violates the whole OOP idea of encapsulation.*  The best code is the easiest to write and easiest to understand. Classes are not everything. To be more blatand *[OOP is bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM1iUe6IofM)*

Comment: Why not do the generation in that "display window"? If you do that, you can implement your loop as it is (use `Control.Refresh()` method to redraw a control, by the way).